# Reading bytes from Python String

Tags: python, string, hex

I have hex data in a string. I need to be able parse the string byte by byte, but through reading the docs, the only way to get data bytewise is through the f.read(1) function.

How do I parse a string of hex characters, either into a list, or into an array, or some structure where I can access byte by byte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mystring = "a1234f"
data = list(mystring)
```

Data will be a list where each element is a character from the string.

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like what you might really want (Python 2.x) is:

```
from binascii import unhexlify
mystring = "a1234f"
print map(ord,unhexlify(mystring))
```

> [161, 35, 79]

This converts each pair of hex characters into its integer representation.

In Python 3.x, you can do:

```
>>> list(unhexlify(mystring))
[161, 35, 79]
```

But since the result of `unhexlify` is a byte string, you can also just access the elements:

> ```
> >>> L = unhexlify(string)
> >>> L
> b'\xa1#O'
> >>> L[0]
> 161
> >>> L[1]
> 35
> ```

There is also the Python 3 `bytes.fromhex()` function:

```
>>> for b in bytes.fromhex(mystring):
...  print(b)
...
161
35
79
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = 'somestring'
print a[0]        # first byte
print ord(a[1])   # value of second byte

(x for x in a)    # is a iterable generator
```

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate through a string just as you can any other sequence.

```
for c in 'Hello':
  print c
```